# Searching through a dictionary for users input

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello everyone so I have an issue trying to find the user input in a dictionary.

My function is getting data from a website and writing it to a text file. Then transferred into a dictionary, from there I will ask the user to input a country name and it will return the key and the value of that key or the capita income. The issue i am having is that i have to search the dictionary to find the input and if it matches the key then it will print that and the capita income. Im not 100 percent sure what to use if i should use a for function or if my code is correct at the end.

```
def main():
    import requests
    webFile = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2004.txt"
    data = requests.get(webFile) #connects to the file and gest a response object
    with open("capital.txt",'wb') as f:
        f.write(data.content) #write the data out to a file – wb used since thecontent from the response object is returned as abinary object.
    f.close()
    countryName = {}
    with open('capital.txt','r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            num,*key,value = line.split()
            key = ' '.join(key)
            countryName[key] = value.upper()
    userInput = input("Enter a country name: ")
    userInput.upper()
    while(userInput != 'stop'):
            #for loop to see if key is in dictionary
        if userInput in countryName:
            #if(userInput == countryName[key]):
                print("The per capita income in",key, "is",countryName[key])
                userInput = input("Enter a country name: ")
main()
```

```
    while(userInput != 'stop'):
            #for loop to see if key is in dictionary
        if userInput in countryName:
            #if(userInput == countryName[key]):
                print("The per capita income in",key, "is",countryName[key])
                userInput = input("Enter a country name: ")
main()
```

Here is where the issue is, tying to find the if the userInput is the same as the country name key . What would i have to do search the dictionary to match the key to the input, or if there is any uneccesary things in my code.

Comment: Separate IO from logic. That would be your first step.

Comment: `if userInput in countryName:` should do what you want. What's problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

Ah, there was a small issue when comparing the keys. Actually, you were doing `upper()` on the value (a number) which doesn't make sense.
Have a look at this update:

```
import requests
webFile = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2004.txt"
data = requests.get(webFile)
with open("capital.txt",'wb') as f:
  f.write(data.content)
countryName = {}
with open('capital.txt','r') as infile:
  for line in infile:
     num, *key, value = line.split()
     key = ' '.join(key)
     countryName[key.upper()] = value #key.upper() instead of value.upper()
userInput = input("Enter a country name: ").upper()
counter = 0
while not userInput == "STOP": #'STOP' because it's uppercase
   if userInput in countryName:
      print("The per capita income in", userInput, "is", countryName[userInput])
      userInput = input("Enter a country name: ").upper()
   counter += 1
   if counter >= len(countryName): #It couldn't find the country
      userInput = input("Not found. Enter a new country: ").upper()
      counter = 0 #Let's try again
```

And a small improvement: the counter will prevent the infinite loop when the user input doesn't satisfy the `if userInput in countryName` and it's not "stop". Besides that, the "stop" condition must be `"STOP"`, once it'll be in upper case.

Hope it helps

**Update**

As pointed out by @Barmar, another possibility is:

```
countryName = {
   "countryA": "valueA",
   "countryB": "valueB"
}
userInput = "countryA" #Of course, it can be a user input
if userInput in countryName:
   print ("The country is", userInput, "and the value is", countryName[userInput])
```

---

Just a good advice: I think the file part has nothing to do with your question itself, so, next time try to reduce your problem to, you know, something more direct :)

Anyway, you can loop over the keys of `countryName` and then compare with the user input. In other words:

```
countryName = {
   "countryA": "valueA",
   "countryB": "valueB"
}
userInput = "countryA" #Of course, it can be a user input
for key in countryName.keys():
   if userInput == key: #Got it
      print ("The country is", key, "and the value is", countryName[key])
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sweet that worked great i just had to switch that. Just one more question

Comment: @wcosta So i want to make all the names in the text file upper case

Comment: where would i put the .upper() method so that theres no issues with case sensitivity

Comment: Just `f.write(data.content.upper())` should do the trick. If you need a string format for this content, just `my_new_content_as_string = data.content.decode()`

Comment: Just as a side note, it's not necessary to use `f.close()` when you use `with` because it's already handled by this statement :)

Comment: Cool cool, for some reason it only writes the data once, then it only says answer a country name. Is there a misplacement with a line

Comment: @l.m I updated the answer. See if it solves your problem now :)